# Integrable functions that may not satisfy the inversion Fourier formula

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. We define  $\phi_f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\zeta)e^{2\pi i\zeta x}d\zeta$ if the improper Riemann integral is finite otherwise, $\phi_f(x)=\infty$.

1. Does there exist any integrable function $f$ for which $\{x: \phi_f(x)=\infty\}$ enjoys positive measure?
2. Suppose that $\{x: \phi_f(x)=\infty\}$ is a null set (its Lebesgue measure is zero). Could we conclude that $f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\zeta)e^{2\pi i\zeta x}d\zeta$?

p.s. $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: We have $|e^{2\pi i\zeta x}\hat f(\zeta)|=|\hat f(\zeta)|$, so membership in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ doesn't seen to depend on $x$. So the set in your question is either empty or all of $\mathbb R$ for any $f$.

Comment: For an integrable function with nonintegrable Fourier transform, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66173/127263)

Comment: Thanks, I revised the question.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean by "the integral does not exist"? Is your integral supposed to be the Lebesgue integral, in which case you need f-hat to be integrable; or are you taking some kind of improper Riemann integral? Note that since f is integrable, f-hat is continuous and bounded and vanishes at infinity

Comment: @ Yemon Choi, It was done, Riemann integration is requested.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it does show that in a certain sense nothing too dreadful can happen. Namely your integral exists as  a parametric integral in the distributional  sense (a concept which was developed using elementary methods, i.e., without functional analysis, over 50 years ago).  The resulting distribution is equal to your original function

Comment: Kolmogorov constructed an $L^1(T)$ function whose Fourier series diverges everywhere. That would strongly suggest (to me, at least) that there is a similar example in the continuous setting.

Comment: Also, it seems you asked Q2 before, and it was answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376949/on-the-fourier-inversion-formula